# Reading a file and storing all the data in a buffer

Tags: c

I wrote a function to read the entire content of a file and return a pointer to an allocated bufer containing all the data.

Please could you tell me if there is a better way of doing this ? One solution could be to use `stat()` to pre-allocate a buffer and do only one `read()` call but I don't know if it's better, any though ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

char *file_read(const char *path, size_t *file_size)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    char buffer[FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *tmp = NULL;
    char *data = NULL; // The buffer containing the data of the file
    char *data_cursor = NULL; // The current position in the data buffer
    size_t data_size = 0; // The size of the data buffer
    size_t n = 0; // The number of bytes read by fread()

    if (file == NULL)
        goto error;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), file)) > 0) {
        if (data == NULL) {
            data = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
            data_cursor = data;
            data_size = n;
        } else {
            // We compute the position in the buffer as an integer
            // to be able to re-apply after realloc(). Because realloc()
            // can move the pointer we need this position as an integer.
            size_t cursor_pos = data_cursor - data;
            tmp = realloc(data, sizeof(char) * data_size + n);
            if (tmp == NULL)
                goto error;
            data = tmp;
            data_cursor = data + cursor_pos;
            data_size += n;
        }
        memcpy(data_cursor, buffer, n);
    }

    if (ferror(file))
        goto error;

    fclose(file);
    if (file_size != NULL)
        *file_size = data_size;
    return data;

    error:
    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(file);
    if (data != NULL)
        free(data);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Code posted to codereview should compile, it would be great if you could make this a complete file especially could you post the code for `error_set_from_errno_ptr()` ?

Comment: It's just a utility function which stores internally the last errrno & strerror() and return NULL. I replaced it with return NULL in my example. Thanks !

Comment: Here you find how to find size of a file using fseek+ftell, and then allocating a buffer that exact size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957845/using-fseek-and-ftell-to-determine-the-size-of-a-file-has-a-vulnerability After that use rewind and fread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I recommend to pass a file pointer rather than a path. This will enable the code to work with streams as well. It would also simplify the awkward error handling.
- Modern [c](/questions/tagged/c) allows, and recommends, to declare variables closer to their use.
- It is OK to `realloc` even when `data` is `NULL`.
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.
- Incrementing `data_size` *after* `memcpy` lets you drop `data_cursor` and `cursor_pos`, which IMHO obfuscate the code. You'd need to

  ```
      memcpy(data + data_size, buffer, n);
      data_size += n;
  ```
- Allocating an array on the stack is usually not recommended. Consider reading directly into `data + data_size`, and get away without `buffer` and `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those comments, which totally make sense.